# Почему не работает on click после ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Получаю данные с помощью ajax и вставляю их в div, но клик на эти блоки уже не работает. Как это можно исправить?

```
 $('body').find('select').css({ 'display': 'none' });
        $('body').find('label').css({ 'display': 'none' });
        $(".add_to_cart").submit(function (e, addr) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var quantity = $(this).find('select option:selected').val();
            console.log(quantity);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: String($(this).data("action")),
                data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken, quantity: quantity },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('.main-offer_list').html(data);
                    
                }
            });
        });
        $( ".delete-btn" ).on( "click", function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: String($(this).data("delete")),
                data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.main-offer_list').html(data);
                }
            });
      });
```

Comment: Как вариант - слушайте весь документ и ловите всплытие в e.target

Comment: `$('.main-offer_list').on( "click", ".delete-btn", function(e){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что это уже другие блоки.

```
$('.main-offer_list').on("click", ".delete-btn" function(e) {
```